# Migrating from React-Navigation V4 - V5 what happened to CommonActions.init and router.getStateForAction?

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Our app uses `CommonActions.init()` and passes it to `router.getStateForAction`

I'm having two issues here:

1. the `init()` function is no longer in`CommonActions`.
2. the `router.getStateForAction` is no longer available from my `AppNavigator`.

How do I perform these functions with React-Navigation v5?

My AppNavigator is created using the compatibility layer. It looks like the following:

`const AppNavigator = createCompatNavigatorFactory(createStackNavigator)`

My app is throwing an error saying that AppNavigator.router is undefined. So how do I access the router.getSateForAction functionality as well?

Comment: what solution did you use in the end?

Comment: We ended up abandoning the idea. It wasn't a priority.

Answer (score 0):

React Navigation 5 doesn't have static properties like this because it needs to support dynamic routing. To override what happens for actions, you need to pass a custom router.

- Extending navigators: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html#extending-navigators
- Custom routers: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-routers.html