# Implement StackRouter in react navigation v5 for nested routes

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I've got a react native app with the below screen hierarchy

```
RootNavigator
  |
  |---AppNavigatorStack
  |     |--Screen1
  |     |--Screen2
  |
  |---LoginNavigatorStack
        |--loginScreen
        |--forgotPasswordScreen
```

I've been trying to create a `StackRouter` for this workflow

```
const options = {
  initialRouteName: 'LoginNavigatorStack',
}

const routerConfigOptions = {
  routeGetIdList: {},
  routeNames: ["AppNavigatorStack", "LoginNavigatorStack"],
  type: 'stack',
  routeParamList: {}
}

let router = StackRouter(options)
```

How can I configure `routerConfigOptions` to use function like `getStateForAction`, `getInitialState` in StackRouter

Sample code to make a new state

```
const action = CommonActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [{name: "Screen2"}],
})

let newState = router.getStateForAction(state, action, routerConfigOptions)
```

`state` - current state object of the application which we could get from onStateChange of NavigationContainer

The result of newState is null because I haven't added Screen1, Screen2, loginScreen, forgotPasswordScreen in routerConfigOptions

I'm actually expecting a new state which should have the details to navigate to loginScreen.

How can I add all nested screens and create StackRouter for this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's extremely unlikely that you'd need to use the router manually

Comment: I've been using `mobx-state-tree` to do the navigation. Actually, our app is developed on react-navigation v1. I've updated it to v5. So, in v1 there is static property called router in `StackNavigator` which is not available now. So this is the current way. But I haven't seen any proper docs about this. 

This issue also related to mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60326679/migrating-from-react-navigation-v4-v5-what-happened-to-commonactions-init-and

Comment: To customize your navigation in this level you would need to use a custom Nav, that may increase the complexity of your code quite well, did you guys consider using the dynamic routing to switch between navigators? That may save a lot of coding.

Comment: Since you're upgrading to v5, you should take this opportunity to stop using mobx for navigation as well. It'd take less effort to use the React Navigation API rather than trying to hack it to integrate with other state management. You don't really need this kind of integration. Also we don't recommend or officially support doing this.

Comment: @satya164 it is not a hack. We can store the state object in mob or redux and make operations on that state object using `CommonActions`. Then we can assign this state as the navigation container's `initialState`. We are doing all navigation using `navigationRef`. This way, we can easily handle the functionalities like analytics, open the app via push notifications, etc.

Comment: All of those things can be done in an easier way without doing this. It's a bad practice to duplicate state, not only in React Navigation. I maintain React Navigation so I think I can say which practices are hacks or not.

Comment: @satya164 I think you did not understand my requirement. I'm not trying to duplicate the state. We maintain the state object of the navigation container in the mobx. In react-navigation v1 there was an option `getStateForAction` in the router which accept state object and an action from `NavigationAction` then return a new state. `const nextState = getStateForAction(action, prevState)` like this. In v5, I've seen this in custom router section. But, there are no proper examples to do that using stack navigator and StackRouter.

Comment: You said you want to store state in mobx. But anyway, what you're trying to do isn't recommended and can be achieved in a much simpler way by using conditional rendering for auth flow. Your requirement shouldn't be to implement the feature in the same way that was implemented with v1, v5 is not the same, you need to use the new approach to implement that feature.

Comment: My issue has been resolved. I've checked the implementation of the getStateForAction for reset action in the BaseRouter in the react-navigation repo. I have removed the nesting screens and implemented them in one stack. Now I'm getting the state object instead of null. Thank you all for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks more like of react-navigation < 4. I am going to post here, how I do it using react-navigation v5.

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const LoginStack = createStackNavigator();
const AppStack = createStackNavigator();
const RootStack = createStackNavigator();

const LoginStackNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <LoginStack.Navigator>
            <LoginStack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen}/>
            <LoginStack.Screen name="ForgotPasswordScreen" component={ForgotPasswordScreen}/>
        </LoginStack.Navigator>
    )
}

const AppStackNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <AppStack.Navigator>
            <AppStack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1}/>
            <AppStack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2}/>
        </AppStack.Navigator>
    )
}

const RootStackNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <RootStack.Navigator>
            <RootStack.Screen name="LoginStackNavigator" component={LoginStackNavigator}/>
            <RootStack.Screen name="AppStackNavigator" component={AppStackNavigator} />
        </RootStack.Navigator>
    )
}



const App: () => React$Node = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <RootStackNavigator/>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
```

Comment: This is how I have implemented it in my project. But the recommended way is https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#best-practices-when-nesting